# AEM 6.1: Get all 'parsys' and 'iparsys' components of the page

Tags: java, aem

I have a path to the page (/content/my-site/en/cars, for example) and I need a list of all 'parsys' and 'iparsys' components presented on this page in java code. Are there any ways to do it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying a [Sling model](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html) or [WCMUsePOJO](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/cq/sightly/WCMUsePojo.html) to read inner nodes of a page. Here the techniques:

1. If you dont know how many parsys nodes are present: This is not an ideal case since page rendering script dictates all included parsys and iparsys. But just incase, you ll run a query for sling:resourceType like this:

```java
Iterator<Resource> parsysResources = resourceResolver.findResources("/jcr:root/content/my-site/en/cars//*[sling:resourceType='foundation/components/parsys']", Query.XPATH);
Iterator<Resource> iparsysResources = resourceResolver.findResources("/jcr:root/content/my-site/en/cars//*[sling:resourceType='foundation/components/iparsys']", Query.XPATH);
```

2. Similar query but with Query Builder (Recommended): It is recommended to use query builder API for readability and extensible in future.

```java
List<Resource> parsysIpaysysResources = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> predicateMap = new HashMap<>();
predicateMap.put("path", "/content/my-site/en/cars");
predicateMap.put("1_property", "sling:resourceType");
predicateMap.put("1_property.value", "foundation/components/parsys");
predicateMap.put("2_property", "sling:resourceType");
predicateMap.put("2_property.value", "foundation/components/iparsys");
predicateMap.put("p.limit", "-1");

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = resourceResolver.adaptTo(QueryBuilder.class);
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
com.day.cq.search.Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(predicateMap), session);
SearchResult result = query.getResult();
Iterator<Resource> resources = result.getResources();
while (resources.hasNext()) {
    parsysIpaysysResources.add(resources.next());
}
```

3. If the parsys nodes are known to be immediate children of page content, listChildren will be cheaper compared to query.

```java
Page pageContent = pageManager.getContainingPage("/content/my-site/en/cars");
        Iterator<Resource> children = pageContent.getContentResource().listChildren();
        while(children != null && children.hasNext()) {
            Resource child = children.next();
            if(child.isResourceType("foundation/components/parsys") || child.isResourceType("foundation/components/iparsys")) {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

4. If the node name of inner parsys is known, JCR API can be leveraged

```java
Page pageContent = pageManager.getContainingPage("/content/my-site/en/cars");
    Node pageContentNode  = pageContent.adaptTo(Node.class);
    try {
        NodeIterator nodeIter = pageContentNode.getNodes("parsys*");
        // iterate nodes
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```